# css3 cycle words in a list

Tags: css, animation, cycle

I am trying to show one word at a time using the Li entries in a UL. The cycle is achieved with a CSS3 animation. I can show the words in sequence  but not sure how hide the current word before the next one comes in:

```css
#list {position:relative}
#list li {
    animation: showWord 2.5s linear infinite 0s;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}

#list li:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
#list li:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
#list li:nth-child(4) {
 animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
#list li:nth-child(5) {
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes showWord {
 from,
  49.9% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
 
}

/* demo stylin' */

* {
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:courier
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nope**
There is an animation-delay property, but that won't help us here. That delays the start of the animation, but after it's started it runs continuously.

**#Solution:** Keyframes with No Changes

You'll need to do a little mental math:

I want the animation to run for 10 seconds.

*~ plus ~*

I want the animation to delay for 2 seconds in between iterations.

*~ equals ~*

10 total seconds

So when you call the keyframe animation, you use the total seconds,
and the delay takes 2 seconds more each iteration:

```css
#list {position:relative}
#list li {
    animation: showWord 10s linear infinite 0s;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}

#list li:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 2s;
}
#list li:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 4s;
}
#list li:nth-child(4) {
 animation-delay: 6s;
}
#list li:nth-child(5) {
 animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes showWord {
  20%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
/* demo stylin' */

* {
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:courier
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: thank you this, it is spot on. I changed the animation to use visibility to get the no transition effect I was after.

Comment: you're welcome, thumbs up andmark it as solution if it's all ok =)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position: absolute` line

```css
#list {position:relative}
#list li {
    animation: showWord 2.5s linear infinite 0s;
    opacity:0;
}

#list li:nth-child(2) {
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
#list li:nth-child(3) {
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
#list li:nth-child(4) {
 animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
#list li:nth-child(5) {
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes showWord {
 from,
  49.9% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
 
}

/* demo stylin' */

* {
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size:30px;
  font-family:courier
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
 <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```